# How to implement Apostropecms authentication with fusionauth

Tags: fusionauth

I am implementing Apostropecms authentication with fusionauth. For this I use the apostrophe-passport and passport-oauth2 modules. I am having problems at a step in the flow where I must obtain user information. I don't get user information from fusionauth by /oauth2/userinfo or /api/user.

I modified the passport-oauth2 strategy to adapt it to the fusionauth flow.

This is the error:
InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the User API or the Userinfo endpoint in the [verify callback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-oauth2).

To call the [User API](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/users#retrieve-a-user) provide the `accessToken` passed into the verify callback to send to FusionAuth in the `Authorization` header as described in the [API JWT authentication](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/authentication).

Or use the [`Userinfo`](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/oauth/endpoints#userinfo) endpoint as described in the example.